# How to simplify using conjugates in Maple

Tags: maple

I think it is fairly easy to see that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 -1} = \sqrt{2} + 1$$

Now given the fraction on the left in Maple, how can we get to the equivalent expression on the right? I apologize in advance, if this is rather obvious. But after trying a few things, I have not been able to make it work.

I have used `simplify(1/(sqrt(2)-1)` and `simplify(1/(sqrt(2)-1) * ((sqrt(2)+1)/(sqrt(2)+1))`. In both cases, Maple simply returns the first expression on the left $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 -1}$.

Comment: Don’t know Maple, but this process is usually called “rationalizing the denominator.”

Comment: "rationalizing the denominator" is a general term. Using conjugates is one way to rationalize the denominator. I am not sure if conjugates is a term that is being used often, but that is the one I have been taught.

Comment: In *Mathematica*:  `Simplify[1/(Sqrt[2]-1)]` gives the answer.  By the way, this question has little to do with math but explicitly refers to a symbol-manipulation program, and hence should be closed or migrated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a particular software system.... not math per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas, upon looking up rationalizing the denominator, I learnt Maple has a built-in function for this purpose:

`rationalize(1/(sqrt(2)-1))`

gives what I want. For interested reader, [have a look at the documentation page here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=rationalize).